# Update values in multiple columns in table AA with values in the same columns from table B but only if condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, match

I need to update the information in table AA with the information from table BB but only if AA=ID4 matches BB=ID4. Below is the current table layout:

Before Update:

Table AA

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7

10  11  12  13  0   0   0                    
20  21  22  23  0   0   0
```

Table BB

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7

10  11  12  13  14  15  16                    
20  21  22  23  24  25  26
```

After Update:

Table AA

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7

10  11  12  13  14  15  16                    
20  21  22  23  24  25  26
```

The query I built does update information but actually updates all rows not just the rows where
AA=ID4 matches BB=ID4. Here is what I am using:

```
UPDATE AA
   Set AA.ID5 = BB.ID5,
    AA.ID6 = BB.ID6,
    AA.ID7 = BB.ID7
From AA
Inner Join BB
        ON AA.ID4 = BB.ID4
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Thank you in advance

I tried the following suggestion:

```
SQL> merge into aa
2    using bb
3    on (aa.id4 = bb.id4
       and aa.id1 = bb.id1
       and aa.id2 = bb.id2
       and aa.id3 = bb.id3)
4    when matched then update set
5      aa.id5 = bb.id5,
6      aa.id6 = bb.id6,
7      aa.id7 = bb.id7;
```

But I received the following message:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Problem solved with the following query:

```
UPDATE AA
   Set AA.ID5 = BB.ID5,
       AA.ID6 = BB.ID6,
       AA.ID7 = BB.ID7
From AA
Inner Join BB
    ON AA.ID4 = BB.ID4
      AND AA.ID1 = BB.ID1
      AND AA.ID2 = BB.ID2
      AND AA.ID3 = BB.ID3
```

Thank you to Siggemannen for the suggestion that solved this, to Littlefoot for showing me Merge and everyone's input.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? UPDATE FROM is a non-standard syntax.

Comment: I am Using SQL 2014 R2

Comment: You probably mean MS SQL Server 2014.

Comment: what's wrong with your query? it should work on your data example?

Comment: if you want to join on other IDs, then you just add that to your join, like `AA.ID1 = BB.ID1 AND AA.ID2 = BB.ID2 AND AA.ID3 = BB.ID3 AND AA.ID4 = BB.ID4`

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question, if it's significantly different to the provided answer then add it as xn alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

To me, `merge` looks like a good choice.

Sample data; note that I modified the 2nd row in `bb` table so that `id4` doesn't match `aa.id4`:

```
SQL> select * From aa;

       ID1        ID2        ID3        ID4        ID5        ID6        ID7
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10         11         12         13          0          0          0
        20         21         22         23          0          0          0

SQL> select * From bb;

       ID1        ID2        ID3        ID4        ID5        ID6        ID7
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10         11         12         13         14         15         16
        20         21         22         99         24         25         26
                                         ^^
                                        here
```

Merge: only one row will be updated because there's only one match of `aa.id4 = bb.id4`:

```
SQL> merge into aa
  2    using bb
  3    on (aa.id4 = bb.id4)
  4    when matched then update set
  5      aa.id5 = bb.id5,
  6      aa.id6 = bb.id6,
  7      aa.id7 = bb.id7;

1 row merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From aa;

       ID1        ID2        ID3        ID4        ID5        ID6        ID7
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10         11         12         13         14         15         16
        20         21         22         23          0          0          0

SQL>
```

Comment: Table AA has over 2 million records and table BB has about 190k records. ID4 would be the variable information that would be needed to match in order to pull the correct information needed from BB and place it into AA.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. "ID4 would be the *variable information*"? What's that? If ID4 matches in both tables, that query would do its job.

Comment: I am not explaining it correctly. ID1 thru ID4 would always match in both tables. ID5 thru ID7 would be the information that is different in the two tables. ID4 would be the key to grabbing the correct information from table BB to put into table AA.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, that means that the ON clause should be expanded to ID1, ID2 and ID3 (along with ID4).

Comment: I am new to query design so could be doing something wrong but I am Receiving: "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows." Could you provide an example of how the group by would look?

Comment: Maybe I could, if you edit the question and post sample data that illustrates the problem.